# Pycharm database: trigger won't show up when I add it?

Tags: python, sql, pycharm

When I add a trigger using a SQL command run in Python, it executes, but the trigger won't show up in he Database pane of Pycharm? I've got my column folder, my key folder, my foreign keys, and my indices, but where are my triggers? I've already clicked 'Synchronize' and so on.

[image]

What's more, when I try to insert into my table, it complains the trigger is invalid! So these two things may be related? And why does it say the trigger is invalid, yet it doesn't show the trigger in the pane above? What can I do to fix it. The trigger is properly specified!

Comment: Which database is this? What is the exact error you're getting? What's the code of the trigger?

Comment: 1) Oracle, 2) trigger "trigger" is invalid and failed re-validation, 3) the code of the trigger is irrelevant, that is not the problem, since it's an exact copy-paste of code that we know works

Comment: That sounds like an error on the Oracle side of things. I'd say the trigger doesn't work in your environment.